# Group by column value

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module and in admin grid where i am calling module collection.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

I want to use group by a column value in my module table..

I tried this

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
      {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection()->getSelect()->group('column_2');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
      }
```

but it doesn't work its throwing an error

```
Unrecognized method 'setPageSize()'
```

which i am not using anywhere in my grid.php

can anybody suggest me the problem with my code or solution of my problem

Comment: Try this..
$collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->group('column_2');

Comment: Worked Thanks alot @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. can you please tell me what was the problem, when i was using this
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection()->getSelect()->group('column_2');

Answer (score 1):

Check with this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->group('column_2');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: can you tell me the problem with my code?
protected function _prepareCollection()
      {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection()->getSelect()->group('column_2');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
      }

Answer (score 0):

//Try with below code.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->group('column_2');
```